# How do I let R know that my first two columns are time and dates then complete individual time series graphs?

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
DATE        TIME             15          16           17          18        20           22           23           24
30/08/2018  08:00:00    130.4905899 15.44164769 948.9185939 6211.837354 1071.730556 10.08920076 7.793301031 4.290571724
30/08/2018  11:00:00    125.7301547 18.87143833 991.0009783 6304.471569 1082.126629 10.80475415 7.857773565 4.434150761
30/08/2018  14:00:00    153.3779662 17.63335938 949.1741247 6209.524186 1079.102756 10.68438383 8.326058855 4.265092761
30/08/2018  17:00:00    132.3256891 15.8961511  917.0452991 6123.402395 1081.166439 10.41007094 7.856372445 4.19841642
30/08/2018  20:00:00    130.6405835 15.28122651 917.0229181 6135.679239 1084.589394 10.70688202 7.741277402 4.236844143
31/08/2018  08:00:00    124.1484465 17.14357927 948.9060481 6126.791479 1085.907147 10.76713085 7.810187162 4.356138132
03/09/2018  08:00:00    161.0455657 17.10409992 881.4517913 5839.73355  1073.585164 9.925269955 7.987206082 4.301307752
10/09/2018  08:00:00    165.645823  16.45928764 860.4285647 5781.612679 1073.439013 10.01297791 7.983672272 4.257314139
```

Column 1 is the date, column two is the time.  I have completed the following code but just keep getting errors.

Any help?

```
bc <- read.csv("CSV name", header = T)  

bc$DATE = as.POSIXct(strptime(bc$DATE, format="%d-%m-%Y"))

bc$TIME = as.POSIXct(bc$TIME, format="%H-%M-%S"))

library(ggplot2); library(tidyr)

df_tidy <- df %>%

mutate(TIME = row.names %>% as.integer) %>%

select(-row.names) %>%

gather(series, value, -TIME)

ggplot(df_tidy, aes(TIME, value, group = series)) +
geom_line() +
facet_wrap(~series, scales = "free_y")
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I can't read your data.  Please format it as code by adding four (or more) spaces to each line of code.

Comment: Use `as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(bc$DATE, bc$TIME), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))` to create one variable including date and time.

Comment: _csv_ strands for _comma-separated values_. If you have space/tab-separated values, should you not use `sep=""`? Or try `read.table()`

Comment: Have tied up the data is that better?  so should load the data bc <- read.csv("filename", header = TRUE, sep=" ").  There also seems to be an error at mutate?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution, assuming your data.frame is named `df`
It creates a column named `timestamp`, of class POSIXct

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate( timestamp = as.POSIXct( paste0( as.character(DATE), " ", as.character(TIME) ), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S" ) )

#         DATE     TIME      X15      X16      X17      X18      X20      X22      X23      X24           timestamp
# 1 30/08/2018 08:00:00 130.4906 15.44165 948.9186 6211.837 1071.731 10.08920 7.793301 4.290572 2018-08-30 08:00:00
# 2 30/08/2018 11:00:00 125.7302 18.87144 991.0010 6304.472 1082.127 10.80475 7.857774 4.434151 2018-08-30 11:00:00
```